# JavaScript function not working if values passed are blank or null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a JavaScript function for calculating status of the given offer value which is passed as a parameter.

Suppose,  if we have `Values.NE_LEG` as `" "` or `NULL` then it gives as `isNan` error and if affects  my function and doesn't gives status properly.

Below is the function which I am using.

```js
function getHotoStatusIDFTTX(OfferValue) {    
    var Values = JSON.parse(OfferValue);

    var ne_leg = parseFloat(Values.NE_LEG).toFixed(4); //isNan if the value is blank
    var hotoFttxValue = parseFloat(Values.OFFERHOTO).toFixed(4);
    var hotoFttxValuecomplete = parseFloat(Values.HOTOCOMPLETED).toFixed(4);
    var total_hoto = parseFloat(hotoFttxValuecomplete) + parseFloat(hotoFttxValue);
    
    var pendhotoFttxValue = 0;
    var calPerhotofttx = 0;
    var pendPartialfttx = 0;
    var calPartialfttx = 0;

    if (parseFloat(total_hoto).toFixed(2) > 0 && parseFloat(ne_leg).toFixed(2) > parseFloat(total_hoto).toFixed(2)) {
        pendhotoFttxValue = ne_leg - total_hoto;
        calParhotoFttx = (100 - (pendhotoFttxValue * 100 / ne_leg)).toFixed(2);
    } else if (parseFloat(ne_leg).toFixed(2) == parseFloat(total_hoto).toFixed(2)) {
        calParhotoFttx = 100;
    }
    
    var status = 0;
    var toleranceValuefttX = parseFloat(100 - tolerance.percentage);

    if (calParhotoFttx >= toleranceValuefttX) {
        status = HotoStatusId.hoto;
       // status = 11;
    }
    else if (calParhotoFttx < toleranceValuefttX) {
       status = HotoStatusId.hotopartial;
    }  
    return status;
}
```

What is wrong, and what steps should I take?

Comment: check if the value is a number, before trying an operation that would throw an error if it's not a number

Comment: parseFloat(Values.NE_LEG || 0).toFixed(4); // sets default value to "0"

Comment: `NaN` is not an error, it's a value.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky: how can we check that. ?

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant: but its not what I want.. it should set default if it gets `Nan`

Comment: @@Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant: so u mean to say, i need to set default value for all var to 0 ?

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant: i am not getting what exactly needs to be set to default or something else. please help

Comment: [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) combined with default parameters makes it more clear. See specifically Setting a function parameter's default value. The use provides you to pass a parsed object when calling the function, though.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant: can u give one example with relevant to my code. i am unable to understand in the link given

Comment: @BN you should clarify what you want to achieve, simply `parseFloat(Values.NE_LEG || 0)` as @Murali Nepalli pointed out will give you a default value of 0. Also `it gives as isNan error` is quite misleading, as you're not getting any errors in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Use isNan() function.
I think it would help you....

Here's some code for test.

https://jsfiddle.net/pf4mjgnL/2/

```
var str = "avc";
var num = 1234;

console.log(isNaN(str));
console.log(isNaN(num));
```